# How to hide inline Cells

Tags: front-end, options, cells

By giving a cell the simple option `CellOpen -> False`, it can be hidden from view.

But for inline cells (cell within a cell) this does not work.

An option `Visible -> False` only seems to exist for notebooks, not for cells.

What to do?

Comment: One way would be to add a `CellSize` option to the inline cell and toggle between `{0,0}` and `Inherited` but this would be quite messy to implement I think.

Comment: May be you can add an White color or Balck color or other color for all your inline cells and set the content unseen.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to go with stylesheets, you can set `DefaultNewInlineCellStyle` option for `StyleData["Notebook"]` and for this given style, a specific `CellSize`, then you can proceed with toggling it. But it is messy and probably an overreaction.

---

I'd go with this simple procedure, you can put it as a `MenuItem`, a new shortcut or whatever you find convenient. For simplicity let's create a quick palette:

So, first of all, from documentation of `Cells[obj]`:

> `obj` may be a `NotebookObject` or a `CellObject`. If `obj` is a `CellObject`, then `Cells` returns the inline cells in the specified cell.

```
CreatePalette[
   Button[
     "Toggle inline cells visibility",
     Module[{inlineCells},
       inlineCells = Cells /@ Cells @ InputNotebook[] // Flatten;
       If[
          CurrentValue[#, CellSize] === {1, 1},
          SetOptions[#, CellSize -> Automatic],
          SetOptions[#, CellSize -> {1, 1}]
       ] & /@ inlineCells
     ]
   ]
 ]
```

Size `{0,0}` is not supported so we are using `{1, 1}` which is small enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to hide inline cells is by wrapping them in a 0x0 `Pane` or `PaneBox`.  This has the advantage of not requiring one to change the overall `CellSize`, which can be useful in some niche use-cases (like I've run into) where perhaps you want to *obtain* the would-be-size of a cell without showing it.  My use-case for this is a custom "ragged wrapped row/grid" package.

I'm also sharing my routine for obtaining a `CellObject` for an inline cell in the most efficient way I know how to: using `Initialization`. (In practice, using a module / `Unique[]` instead of a global for `cellTagObj` is advised)

```
RawBoxes@RowBox@
  {
   "some dummy contents",
   PaneBox[
    Cell[
     BoxData@Table["aaaaabbbbbcccccddddd", {i, 1, 20}],
     "Output",
     CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}},
     CellFrameMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}},
     ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}},
     CellElementSpacings -> {"CellMinHeight" -> 0, 
       "ClosedCellHeight" -> 0},
     RuleDelayed[Initialization, cellTagObj = EvaluationCell[]]
     ],
    ImageSize -> {0, 0},
    FrameMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}},
    ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}},
    ContentPadding -> False
    ],
   "some more dummy contents"
   }

cellTagObj
AbsoluteOptions[cellTagObj, CellSize]
```

Output:
[image]